# possible to open a document in iOS from HTML5 application and/or native+HTML5?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, document

I would like to know if it is possible that a pure HTML5/Javascript application on iOS call a document so another app shows up and opens it. And what about native+HTML5/Javascript?